# Upgrade Drupal Core from 7.9 to 7.35?

Tags: updating

I've just moved my Drupal site from one host to another, as a complete backup and restore.  I've got a few issues left (images not showing, search not working), but the main thing is, on my status reports, it shows my Drupal Core installed version being 7.9, but the recommended version being 7.35.

As a Drupal novice, can anyone explain how I Have version 7.9 when the latest core is 7.35, AND, if I "upgrade" to 7.35, am I likely to encounter any significant problems?

Thanks
Carlton

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone explain how I Have version 7.9 when the latest core is 7.35

Drupal core need to be updated a regular intervals. This does not happen automatically. If Drupal 7.9 was the version you installed, it will stay at that version until you update.  Moving hosts does not update anything.  *All* Drupal versions prior to ver. 7.32 suffered from a critical security vulnerability (see [SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005) for details).  I would strongly recommend that you take your site offline *until* it is properly upgraded from 7.9 to the latest version (currently 7.35).

Upgrading Drupal core is usually painless if you've got *drush* installed, even if going over several generations.  The command to use (you do this in the CLI) is:

```
drush up drupal -y
```

Sit back and watch *drush* sort out all the interdependencies.

Best of luck!